# x86_64 align stack and recover without saving registers

Tags: c, stack, alignment, x86-64

I'm writing interrupt handling routines for x86_64. The ABI specifies that before calling a C function I must align the stack to 16 bytes. The x86_64 ISA specifies that on entry to an ISR, my stack is 8 byte aligned. I need to align my stack pointer to 16 bytes therefore. The issue is that on return from my C function, I must recover the (potentially) unaligned stack pointer so that I can return from my interrupt correctly.

I wonder if there is a way to do this without using a general purpose register?

Comment: @H2CO3 That sounds like a terrible idea. I also don't have the notion of a heap in this context.

Comment: OK, it was just a qiick idea.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use a register at all? Could push the old RSP if you could save it to a register first.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I'm asking if there's a way to do it without using another register. It is trivial if I can use one.

Comment: @dschatz: I figured you had that odd restriction, just wanted to ask before answering.

Comment: Hmm.. If you subtract 4 bytes from %esp and push %eax, this swaps the 16-byte alignment state and gives you a register to play with and space to store the current SP.  You can use the register an dsome bit-twiddles/tests to check the new %esp alignment state. If it's OK then carry on, if it's not, subtract another 8 bytes from %esp and copy down the stored 'old' %esp and %eax from the frame above.  IRET should be OK in either case since the frame above contains the correct registers in both cases.  DISCLAIMER - NOT TESTED!  just a first idea, may not work..

Comment: Pushing a register to free it up for the aligning operation is the way it is usually done (as in my answer). No need for additional subtraction, tests or bit fiddeling. Note that registers are 8 byte wide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's my solution to the question as put:

```
pushq %rsp
pushq (%rsp)
andq $-0x10, %rsp
    call function
movq 8(%rsp), %rsp
```

The two pushes leave the stack with the same alignment it had originally, and a copy of the original `%rsp` at `(%rsp)` and `8(%rsp)`.  The `andq` then aligns the stack - if it was already 16 byte aligned nothing changes, if it was 8 byte aligned then it subtracts 8 from `%rsp`, meaning that the original `%rsp` is now at `8(%rsp)` and `16(%rsp)`.  So we can unconditionally restore it from `8(%rsp)`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way doing it without a additional register, because the align operation is destructive to the `rsp` register. You need to do something along

```
push %rbp          ;save rbp for stack pointer
mov  %rsp, %rbp    ;move old sp to rbp
and  $-0x10, %rsp  ;align stack
...                
...                ;if you want to use %rbp here, save it on the stack before
...  
mov  %rbp, %rsp    ;old stack pointer
pop  %rbp
iret
```

Comment: You haven't convinced me that there is no way, though I suspect it is the case. Just because the operation is destructive doesn't mean I can't do something before the align to save the original stack pointer.

Comment: Well, there is one way: You could push the stack pointer and then a magic number to stack. Because not all addresses in the 64 bit address space are currently allowed in x86_64, you can choose a magic which can't possibly be a stack address. On return you search for the magic and find the stack pointer behind it. If the gap between aligned stack and old stack contains the magic by random chance, you can identify this case because you will find the magic two times.

Comment: Using `%rbp` is a good choice here, because it's a callee-saved register (so the C function will restore it before returning, if it clobbers it).

Answer (score 1):

Probably slower than using %ebp as others have described, but how about:

```
    push %rsp
    test $0xf, %rsp
    jz aligned
    push (%rsp)   // duplicate the top of the stack
aligned:
    // now have 16-byte alignment with the original stack pointer
    // on the top of the stack, either once or twice
         :
    pop %rsp
    iret
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the stack is already 8-byte aligned, and that a push instruction can read the value to be pushed from memory.

Comment: Now the're a conditional push but unconditional pop. Very problematic.

Comment: @R: why? The unconditional pop modifies the stack pointer so it undoes  things regardless of what the condition was.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Very clever! I like it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the only way to do it without using an additional register requires additional writing and reading to memory which would be the only point of not using an additional register.

I'll offer the current solution I have. I store rbp so I can use it for temporary storage and then restore it before the call to the function. This is similar to drhirsch's answer

```
movq    %rbp, -24(%rsp) //store original rbp 3 words beyond the stack
movq    %rsp, %rbp //store original rsp
subq    $8, %rsp //buy a word on the stack
andq    $-0x10, %rsp //16 byte align the stack (growing downwards)
//We now have 1 or 2 words free on the stack (depending on the original
// alignment). This is why we put rbp 3 words beyond the stack
movq    %rbp, (%rsp) //store the original rsp right here
movq    -24(%rbp), %rbp //restore original rbp
call    foo
movq    (%rsp), %rsp //restore original rsp
iretq
```

Comment: This isn't safe against nested interrupts - if a higher priority interrupt hits you after you store to `-24(%rsp)` and before you adjust `%rsp`, it'll clobber your saved `%rbp`.