# Padding and alignment in Protostar Stack0

Tags: c, memory-alignment, exploit

This morning I ran through the [stack0](https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/) exercise on protostar. The example is a simple stack overflow using gets. I compiled the code using gcc on x86-64 with the stack protector and ASLR enabled.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    volatile int modified;
    char buffer[64];

    modified = 0;
    gets(buffer);

    if(modified != 0) {
        printf("you have changed the 'modified' variable\n");
    } else {
        printf("Try again?\n");
    }
}
```

Since an int is 4 bytes, and is pushed on the stack before buffer, 64 bytes of char, I had thought that I would need to overflow buffer by 1 byte in order to change the value of modified.

However, this didn't work. Therefore, I next thought that the compiler had inserted 4 bytes of padding between modified and buffer such that both start on a word boundary (8 bytes of x86-64). However, this didn't work either.

Finally, I ran the executable in GDB and found that infact, GCC is inserting 12 bytes of alignment between modified and buffer: therefore I had to write 77 bytes into buffer in order to overflow in modified (the 77th byte being the first byte of modified).

```
(gdb) p &modified
$3 = (volatile int *) 0x7fffffffdadc

(gdb) p &buffer[63]
$12 = 0x7fffffffdacf ""
```

Hence, 0x7fffffffdadc - 0x7fffffffdacf is 13 bytes.

```
0000000000400504 <main>:
400504: 55                      push   %rbp
400505: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
400508: 48 83 ec 60             sub    $0x60,%rsp
40050c: 89 7d ac                mov    %edi,-0x54(%rbp)
40050f: 48 89 75 a0             mov    %rsi,-0x60(%rbp)
400513: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
40051a: 48 8d 45 b0             lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
40051e: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
400521: e8 ea fe ff ff          callq  400410 <gets@plt>
```

Now, looking at the object code above, we can see that GCC allocates 96 bytes on the stack `sub $0x60, %rsp` for both buffer and modified.

Then, it moves the destination index and source index into the address -0x54 and -0x60 from %rbp. What is the purpose of this and what do these registers do?

Next, I can see that modified is set to 0 with `movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)`, where it is 4 bytes from the base pointer. There is therefore 12 bytes between the end of buffer and the first byte of modified.

Hence, my question is: why does GCC insert 12 bytes of alignment between modified and buffer, to make modified 16 byte aligned, rather than just 8 byte aligned, which would align it with the word boundary on x86-64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack alignment is governed by platform ABI, not only by particular type alignment. In your case the stack alignment is 16 bytes, which is common for x86_64 platforms.

You can run a search for x86_16 ABI questions like: [x86_64 align stack and recover without saving registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592345/x86-64-align-stack-and-recover-without-saving-registers)